# Checkout form validation Magento 2

Tags: magento2, vat

I think that I'm going crazy, how can I add the "**required**" attribute to Vat number and company field in the checkout form??

Comment: Do you want to set required only for checkout form or all forms where vat number and company field is display?

Answer (score 0):

That should do it:

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `is_required` = '1' WHERE `eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = 36;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set requried field from the admin also for that 
Goto `Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration`
and open `Name and Address Options` section there are setting for `Show Company` and `Show Tax/VAT Number` choose `Required` from dropdown and save Configuration and clear cache.